# Directional Derivatives Question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

A bushwalker is climbing a mountain, of which the equation is $f(x,y)=400-\frac{x^2+4y^2}{10000}$. The buswalker is at a point P=(-1600,-400). What is the slope of the mountain at P in the direction of the peak?

I'm having trouble computing the vector for the peak. The rest should be straight forward.

Comment: How do you interpret the peak? Can you think of it as the extreme value of something in your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- find the coordinates of the peak $Q(a,b)$, that is the point of maximum for $f$ (we don't need derivatives to guess it)
- determine the gradient vector $\nabla f(P)$ at $P(-1600,-400)$ and recall that for a given direction expressed by the normal vector $\vec v$ the slope is given by $\nabla f(P)\cdot \vec v$

Comment: I think Q(0,0) maximises f. But how does this relate to the vector v?

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney the directon from $P$ to $Q$ is $w=Q-P=(1600,400)$

Comment: I underatand, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney Well done! You are welcome, bye!